# Python in x for loop 0,3 use x in a variable

Tags: python, for-loop

Just a newbie learning python.

I have a list of tweets in json. Every tweet has a text, a url, an image and so on.

I want to access for instance the url from tweet2 so I can use that variable to tweet it.

Like so:

```
tte2 =  data['tweets']['tweet2']['tte']
print "tte2 is ", tte2
```

The json file I have can hold multiple tweets. To know how many I use the variable numtweets

```
numtweets =  len(tweets)
print "how many tweets do we have", numtweets
```

I have figured out a way to fill variables while looping over the dictionary like this:

```
for x in range (1, numtweets):
   print x
   tweetN = 'tweet{}' .format(x)
   print "tweetN is", tweetN
   ttd[x] =  data['tweets']['tweetN']['ttd'] .format(tweetN)
```

But I cannot find a way for tweetN to be the context of the variable tweetN. It takes it litterally.  Is there a way to do this or is there a different approach?

Something like '\'tweetN\' or something?

I hope I am clear enough?

Comment: Why don't you just use the variable? data['tweets'][tweetN]

Comment: Do you care what "number" each tweet is? Why not just iterate over them: `for tweet in data['tweets'].values()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a literal string where you should be using the variable.

```
data['tweets'][tweetN]['ttd']
```

Note, this is a fairly strange structure: normally you'd expect `data['tweets']` to be a list, which you could iterate through directly.

Comment: You saved my day! Each tweet holds three or more values, url, image and text. text for different languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

A better way, I think, to do this would be:

```
for tweetN, tweet in data['tweets'].items():
  ttd[int(tweetN[5:])] = tweet['ttd']
```

However, this is really a very messy structure. If you don't need the numbers of tweets, you can just do:

```
for tweet in data['tweets'].values():
  ttd.append(tweet['ttd'])
```